# Bitcoind daemon - network syncronizing error

Tags: bitcoind

I have bitcoind installed on a VPS debian server, i started bitcoind 2 days ago for syncronizing with bitcoin network but i got the following error today.

```
        root@vps:~# bitcoind getinfo
    {
        "version" : 32400,
        "balance" : 0.00000000,
        "blocks" : 258354,
        "connections" : 9,
        "proxy" : "",
        "generate" : false,
        "genproclimit" : -1,
        "difficulty" : 112628548.66634709,
        "hashespersec" : 0,
        "testnet" : false,
        "keypoololdest" : 1397553052,
        "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
        "errors" : "EXCEPTION: 11DbException       
\nDb::put: Cannot allocate memory       \nbitcoin in ProcessMessage()       \n"
    }
```

I have no idea what this error mean, or how can i  resolve this kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error "EXCEPTION: 11DbException
Db::put: Cannot allocate memory       bitcoin in ProcessMessage() " is comming because you are using a very old version of bitcoind(0.3.24) . I had the same problem and I upgraded it to the latest bitcoind version(0.9.3) and now every thing is working fine for me. So I will suggest you to upgrate it ASAP.

You can see below now its working for me -

Array
(
    [version] => 90300
    [protocolversion] => 70002
    [walletversion] => 10500
    [balance] => 0
    [blocks] => 299134
    [timeoffset] => -73
    [connections] => 32
    [proxy] => 
    [difficulty] => 8000872135.9682
    [testnet] => 
    [keypoololdest] => 1415022680
    [keypoolsize] => 101
    [paytxfee] => 0
    [relayfee] => 1.0E-5
    [errors] => 
)